# automatically updating vba concatenate column when changed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm concatenating 4 different formula based columns into one using VBA (to be able to change formatting while still concatenating). The concatenating VBA code works, but when the 4 individual columns update and pull the new information, the concatenated column doesn't change.

My concatenated code is this and it lies in column D or 4:

```
Sub joint1()

ActiveSheet.Range("a2", ActiveSheet.Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Select
Row = 2
Col = 4
For Each Cell In Selection
AE = Cells(Row, Col + 15)
Name = Cells(Row, Col + 9)
SC = Cells(Row, Col + 16)
PM = Cells(Row, Col + 10)

Cells(Row, Col) = Name & Chr(10) & "(" & AE & " - " & SC & ")" & Chr(10) & PM & " - PM"

With Cells(Row, Col)
    .ClearFormats
    .Characters(1, Len(Name)).Font.Bold = True

End With
Row = Row + 1
Next
End Sub
```

If you know how to add a feature to help my problem, I would be very appreciative!

Comment: Try adding `Option Explicit` to the start of your module. This won't solve your problem directly, but it will show you where things might be going wrong. I tried your code and it didn't work at all, all your variables will be of type variant, and things might not be getting copied as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub joint1()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngSelect As Range
Dim Name As String

Set rngSelect = ActiveSheet.Range("a2", ActiveSheet.Range("a2").End(xlDown))
iRow = 2
iCol = 4

For Each rng In rngSelect
    Name = Cells(iRow, iCol + 9)
    Cells(iRow, Col) = "=M" & iRow & Chr(10) & " & ""("" & S" & iRow & " & "" - "" & T" & iRow & " & "")"" &" & Chr(10) & "N" & iRow & " & ""-PM"""
    With Cells(iRow, iCol)
        .ClearFormats
        .Characters(1, Len(Name)).Font.Bold = True
    End With
    iRow = iRow + 1
Next

End Sub
```

This code creates a formula in each cell, rather than just copying the values.

The job could probably be done just as well with an excel formula. The formatting doesn't work with my version of excel (2007).

Comment: Thanks, that works and turns it into a formula. The point of me using VBA, though, was to be able to have the a different format for each of the columns I'm concatenating into one. I originally did it with a normal formula like this, but found out it needed to be done in VBA to get the results I needed. For example, I want only the name column to be bolded, not the whole cell. If you know how to fix that it would be an extreme help! Thanks.